# What's the meaning of this sed command? sed 's%^.*/%%'

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I saw a bash command `sed 's%^.*/%%'`

Usually the common syntax for sed is `sed 's/pattern/str/g'`, but in this one it used `s%^.*` for the `s` part in the `'s/pattern/str/g'`.

My questions:
What does `s%^.*` mean?
What's meaning of `%%` in the second part of `sed 's%^.*/%%'`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `%` is an alternative delimiter so that you don't need to escape the forward slash contained in the matching portion.

So if you were to write the same expression with `/` as a delimiter, it would look like:

```
sed 's/^.*\///'
```

which is also kind of difficult to read.

Either way, the expression will look for a forward slash in a line; if there is a forward slash, remove everything up to and including that slash.

Comment: Yes. Additionnal note: it uses the *last* slash in the line.

Comment: Also worth noting, it functions similarly to `basename` (without the suffix argument) except that it will remove everything if the string ends in a slash and `basename` won't.

Answer (score 1):

the usually used delimiter is `/` and the usage is `sed 's/pattern/str/'`.

At times you find that the delimiter is present in the pattern. In such a case you have a choice to either escape the delimiter found in the pattern or to use a different delimiter. In your case a different delimiter `%` has been used.

The later way is *recommended* as it keeps your command *short and clean*.