# Why can s command of sed can be followed by a comma?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, gnu, utility

I saw someone use an expression like: `sed -e 's, *$,,'`
does anybody know why we can use it like this, and what does it do?

I thought the s command should be `sed -e 'addr,addrs/reg/sub/'` ?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508651/whats-the-meaning-of-this-sed-command-sed-s

Comment: Was your issue solved, @dspjm ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Using different delimiters in sed](http://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/):

> sed takes whatever follows the "s" as the separator

It is a good way to avoid escaping too much. Code is more readable if you use a delimiter that is not present in the string you want to handle.

For example let's say we want to replace `lo/bye` from a string. With `/` as delimiter it would be a little messy:

```
$ echo "hello/bye" | sed 's/lo\/bye/aa/g'
helaa
```

So if we define another separator it is more clear:

```
$ echo "hello/bye" | sed 's|lo/bye|aa|g'
helaa
$ echo "hello/bye" | sed 's,lo/bye,aa,g'
helaa
```